# Roslyn Get method invocation references in solution

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, code-analysis

I've created a very simple Solution with two projects inside it using .NET framework 4.6

#### TestReference.Data.dll

`DataRepository.cs`

```c#
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestReferences.Data
{
    public class DataRepository
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> GetProductNames()
        {
            return Enumerable.Repeat("Prod Name", 30);
        }

        public IEnumerable<int> GetProductIds()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(12, 13);
        }
    }
}
```

`ProductService.cs`

```c#
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestReferences.Data
{
    public class ProductService : IProductService
    {
        private readonly DataRepository dataRepository;

        public ProductService()
        {
            dataRepository = new DataRepository();
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> GetRecentProductNames()
        {
            return this.dataRepository.GetProductNames();
        }

        public IEnumerable<int> GetRecentProductIds()
        {
            return this.dataRepository.GetProductIds();
        }
    }
}
```

`IProductService.cs`

```c#
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestReferences.Data
{
    public interface IProductService
    {
        IEnumerable<int> GetRecentProductIds();
        IEnumerable<string> GetRecentProductNames();
    }
}
```

#### TestReference.Web.dll

an MVC project that has a reference to the TestReference.Data.dll

`HomeController.cs`

```c#
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TestReferences.Data;

namespace TestReferences.Web.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        IProductService productService;

        public HomeController()
        {
            this.productService = new ProductService();
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            this.productService.GetRecentProductIds();
            this.productService.GetRecentProductNames();

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            this.productService.GetRecentProductNames();

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

In that structure, if you open `ProductService.cs` and place the cursor over `GetRecentProductNames` then press `shift + F12` it shows 2 results in `TestReference.Web` (Code-lens shows one more in the interface, only for Enterprise editions ).
I've created another console application to get the same references.

```c#
public static void Main()
{
    MSBuildWorkspace ms =  MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
    Solution solution = ms.OpenSolutionAsync(@"D:\SampleApps\TestReferences\TestReferences.sln").Result;

    Document doc = solution
        .Projects
        .Where(p => p.Name == "TestReferences.Data")
        .SelectMany(p => p.Documents)
        .FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == "ProductService.cs");

    if (doc == null)
    {
        throw new NullReferenceException("DOc");
    }

    SemanticModel model = doc.GetSemanticModelAsync().Result;

    List<MethodDeclarationSyntax> methodDeclarations = doc.GetSyntaxRootAsync().Result.DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>().ToList();

    // Method declaration is GetRecentProductNames()
    MethodDeclarationSyntax m = methodDeclarations.First();

    ISymbol symbolInfo = model.GetDeclaredSymbol(m);

    IEnumerable<ReferencedSymbol> references = SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(symbolInfo, doc.Project.Solution).Result;
}
```

I receive two items inside the `references`, but their locations are 0.

> [0] | GetRecentProductNames, 0 refs
>   [1] | GetRecentProductNames, 0 refs

It's my first touch with Roslyn and `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis`. The Version of the library is

```
<package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis" version="2.6.1" targetFramework="net46" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`GetDeclaredSymbol` returns the associated symbol if its a declaration syntax node. This is not what you're looking for.

You should use `GetSymbolInfo` to get the symbol information about a syntax node:

```
var symbolInfo = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(m);
var references = SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(symbolInfo, doc.Project.Solution).Result;
```

Comment: If I use `ISymbol symbolInfo = model.GetSymbolInfo(m).Symbol;` it returns null.

Comment: Check if the project has references to the other project. If not, you need to add these references manually.

Comment: Yes of course, the MVC project has reference to the the Data project. The main method that you can see in the post is executing in a separate console application which is doesn't have any references.

Comment: I ment the MSBuildWorkspace object.

Comment: After execute `ms.OpenSolutionAsync(` the ms.CurrentSolution.Projects => shows 2 `TestReference.Data.dll, TestReference.Web.dll`

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was trying to achieve the same functionality as `View Call Hierarchy` which is embedded in Visual Studio 2017. Just right click over method.